# Passive form + くれる

Tags: grammar, phrases

For a while now I've been trying to write "[I'm happy that] X chose me", and I've come across the following:

```
Xが選んでくれて
Xに選ばれてくれて
Xに選んでもらって
```

Where the second option (passive + くれる) actually seems to have the most number of hits, despite me having never learned it and no English sites explaining it either. But I can't make sense of it. くれる talks about the giver, while the passive form refers to the speaker/receiver. What does this structure mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aが Xに 選ばれてくれて 私はうれしい means "I'm glad that X chose A / A is chosen by X". It indicates that compared with X, A is closer to 私 and 私 thanks A.

Xに選ばれてくれて can't mean "X chose me" unless you see the situation from a different viewpoint.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense. But by 私 thanks A do you mean 私 thanks X (for choosing A)?

Comment: As I wrote, I mean "私 thanks A". The one chosen by X is A, so the one who 私 thanks is A. That's how the passive sentence works with くれて.